# Angular 8, how can I use the primary outlet route when i'm in another router outlet

Tags: angular, router, outlet

sorry I'm new to Angular and don't understand very well how router outlet works.

```
    {path: 'organisation/:orga_id/event/:event_id', component: EventAdminComponent, children: [
            {path: 'general', component: GeneralComponent, outlet: 'tab'},
            {path: 'tickets', component: TicketsComponent, outlet: 'tab'},
            {path: 'commandes', component: TestSecondComponent, outlet: 'tab'},
            {path: 'stat', component: TestSecondComponent, outlet: 'tab'}
        ]},
    {path: 'organisation/:orga_id/event/:event_id/status-people/:ticket_id', component: StatusPeopleComponent},
```

So, this is my app-routing.ts, i used a tab router outlet in a page, my route is currently:

> http://localhost:4200/admin/organisation/KHY1ODY0ZDUx/event/GKniQWmuVDM2/(tab:tickets)

As you can see i find myself in the router outlet named tab, what i want is: From where i am return to the primary outlet and go to this url :

> http://localhost:4200/admin/organisation/KHY1ODY0ZDUx/event/GKniQWmuVDM2/status-people/:ticket-id

I tried a lot of things with routerLink, but nothing worked, can someone explain me how should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to navigate to a URL directly:

```
[routerLink]="['/foo/bar']"
```

you have to set the outlets manually, for example like this:

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: '/foo/bar', tab: null } }]"
```

This will open `'/foo/bar'` in the `primary` outlet and clear the `tab` outlet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tryied your solution and what i got is an url like this: http://localhost:4200/admin/organisation/KHY1ODY0ZDUx/event/GKniQWmuVDM2/(tab:tickets(//admin/organisation/KHY1ODY0ZDUx/event/GKniQWmuVDM2/status-people/:ticket-id))

Comment: What does your routerLink-value look like?

Comment: `[routerLink]= "[{ outlets: { primary: '/admin/organisation/' + manageEvent.orgaId + '/event/' + manageEvent.eventId + '/status-people/' + item.id, tab: null } }]">`. And the result of this value is the url above.